# Robolectric + Maven

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am new to using Robolectric with Maven for an Android project.

Here is the test case (it doesn't really do anything)

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class UTest {

private SplashActivity mActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SplashActivity.class).create().get();
    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.signInProgress);
}



@Test
public void testingMe() throws Exception {

}
}
```

However, when this is run against maven using the target test, I get the following exception:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: immutable!
    at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle$ResMap.merge(ResBundle.java:128)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle$ResMap.access$100(ResBundle.java:116)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResBundle.mergeLibraryStyle(ResBundle.java:88)
    at org.robolectric.res.OverlayResourceLoader.doInitialize(OverlayResourceLoader.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.res.XResourceLoader.initialize(XResourceLoader.java:29)
    at org.robolectric.res.XResourceLoader.getValue(XResourceLoader.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.res.OverlayResourceLoader.getValue(OverlayResourceLoader.java:58)
    at org.robolectric.res.RoutingResourceLoader.getValue(RoutingResourceLoader.java:31)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowAssetManager.java:263)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowAssetManager.java:259)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getResourceText(ShadowAssetManager.java:62)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:225)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:313)
    at ****.loadRestServerUrl(****.java:417)
    at ****.onCreate(****.java:201)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:146)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:387)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:227)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?  I am using Robolectric 2.1.1.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with `3.0-rc2`

Comment: @HieuRocker This post is almost 2 years old. You should be using `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`.

Comment: @TLam What is the status of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with multiple threads accessing resources, causing Robolectric to attempt to load the resources concurrently.

I fixed this in https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2353.  If you use the latest snapshot, it should work, or you can wait for the 3.1 release.

As a temporary measure, if you just force loading a resource in `Application#onCreate()` (such as by calling `getString(R.string.whatever`) or some other method that will be run before any additional threads are created, it will ensure the resources have been loaded before multiple threads try to use them.

Comment: Hi @Scott Kennedy,
Please help, how can we force loading resource in Application#onCreate() ?

Comment: Just call getString() :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. Your answer should be marked as the right one.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the error, you are getting. But I tried this in other way.
Can you try this ?

```
private MainActivity activityMain;
private EditText edtTxtOne;
private EditText edtTxtTwo;
private Button btnDiv;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activityMain = new MainActivity();
    activityMain.onCreate(null);
    btnDiv = (Button) activityMain.findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    edtTxtOne = (EditText) activityMain.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtNumberOne);
    edtTxtTwo = (EditText) activityMain.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtNumberTwo);
}

@Test
public void testDivButton() {}
```

}

Comment: @Degen, your point is that, we cannot create object instance with new operator in robolectric for activity classes ?